# Unable to do git push from jenkins when creating a new branch

Tags: git, jenkins, git-branch, jenkins-git-plugin

I am creating a new git branch from Jenkins (execute shell) using the below commands but when I run this job , it creates the branch locally but doesn't push it to the origin. Also this Jenkins job just stuck at the git-push command and never completes. I think I am missing something somewhere due to which it is not able to push.

**git fetch origin old-branch:new-branch
git checkout new-branch
git push -u origin new-branch**

Did I missed anything ?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The commands you have mentioned are correct and there seems to be no issue in that.

```
git fetch origin master:newbranch 
git checkout newbranch 
git push -u origin newbranch
```

In this particular order.

Please check is the user with which Jenkins jobs are running has sufficient privileges to create branch in the git repository.

And by stuck what do you mean, does it timeout or gives any error.